# Random Character Generation Error C#

Tags: c#, debugging, random

For some reason, when I try to generate this code all at once, the code produces the same number or letter over and over again (30 times) - see below. When I go through line by line in debug mode, however, the code works great...

```
private string Generate_ActiveX_name()
{

    StringBuilder charBuilder = new StringBuilder("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ");
    StringBuilder numBuilder = new StringBuilder("0123456789");
    // 
    // Holds Active X Key (final)
    //
    StringBuilder activeX_builder = new StringBuilder();

    // Determine charactar or number


    while (activeX_builder.Length < 30)
    {

        Random activeX_gen = new Random();

        switch (activeX_gen.Next(0, 2))
        {
            case 0:
                Random charSelection = new Random();
                int CharSelected = charSelection.Next(0, 53);
                activeX_builder.Append(charBuilder[CharSelected]);
                break;
            case 1:
                Random numSelection = new Random();
                int NumSelected = numSelection.Next(0, 10);
                activeX_builder.Append(numBuilder[NumSelected]);
                break;

        }
    }

    string activeX_key = activeX_builder.ToString().Substring(0, 8) + "-";
    activeX_key += activeX_builder.ToString().Substring(8, 4) + "-";
    activeX_key += activeX_builder.ToString().Substring(12, 4) + "-";
    activeX_key += activeX_builder.ToString().Substring(16, 11);

    return activeX_key;

}
```

Why does this code fail when I run it through all at once?

Thanks,
Evan

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to move the `Random` constructor out of your loop.  Change this:

```
while (activeX_builder.Length < 30)
{
    Random activeX_gen = new Random();
```

To:

```
Random activeX_gen = new Random();
while (activeX_builder.Length < 30)
{
```

The issue is that, when an instance of `Random` is created, it uses the current system clock as a "seed" value for the random number generation.  Since your routine runs very quickly, the same seed is chosen every time, so you get the same "random" value.  When you're debugging, you're slowing it down (by stepping) enough that a different seed is chosen in each loop, and you get truly random values.

If you move it out of the loop, then a single `Random` instance will be created, which will lead to a random distribution (and more efficiency!).

Comment: Where did you learn all of this ... jeez I envy you! I will mark yours as correct.

Comment: your solution will not work as expected. If try the running the code, you will see that before the changes the generated guid would have the same char inside like `99999999-9999-9999-99999999999`, after applying the fix you suggested the guid will always have two chars like this `r333r333-r3rr-rrrr-33rr333rrr3`.

Comment: It does work ... Just take out the randoms from inside the loop. Works fine.

Comment: @Alex: I didn't show ALL of the changes required, but rather just the core concept.  Using a single random instance outside of the loop will correct the issue entirely.

Comment: @Evan: If your goal is to generate random GUID instances, you should just use `Guid.NewGuid()` - that will be much simpler and more reliable.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you are trying to generate GUID.

You can do this with one line

```
var guid = Guid.NewGuid();
```

However, here is the fix to your code:

```
private static string Generate_ActiveX_name()
{
    StringBuilder charBuilder = new StringBuilder("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ");
    StringBuilder numBuilder = new StringBuilder("0123456789");
    StringBuilder activeX_builder = new StringBuilder();


    Random activeX_gen = new Random();
    while (activeX_builder.Length < 30)
    {
        switch (activeX_gen.Next(0, 2))
        {
            case 0:
                int CharSelected = activeX_gen.Next(0, 53);
                activeX_builder.Append(charBuilder[CharSelected]);
                break;
            case 1:
                int NumSelected = activeX_gen.Next(0, 10);
                activeX_builder.Append(numBuilder[NumSelected]);
                break;
        }
    }

    string activeX_key = activeX_builder.ToString().Substring(0, 8) + "-";
    activeX_key += activeX_builder.ToString().Substring(8, 4) + "-";
    activeX_key += activeX_builder.ToString().Substring(12, 4) + "-";
    activeX_key += activeX_builder.ToString().Substring(16, 11);

    return activeX_key;
}
```

Two problems:

1. You don't need more than one instance of Random class: `charSelection` and `numSelection` are redundant.
2. Instantiate Random class one time, not inside of the while loop.

**[Edit]**

8-4-4-11 format:

```
var guidText = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
var customGuid = guidText.Substring(0, 18) + guidText.Substring(23, 12);
```

Comment: @Alex I love your GUID solution! Damn I'm such an idiot. Is there a way to modify the guid output so that it produces characters in the following format: 8-4-4-11? Rather than 8-4-4-4-11

Comment: I just got back here - let me give it a go.

Comment: @Alex Code worked absolutely perfect. Just me being curious - is there a specific reason as to why you used ToString("D") as opposed to just ToString() ?

Comment: @Evan - no good reason. Was playing with different formats, and left D there, which is the default format.